# Kivy - Label text = data (all) from mysql query

Tags: mysql, kivy, kivy-language

How to display on Label text, all data I've got from mysql query?

If I print "cont_number" in console displays everything fine (multiple rows) but in Kivy file only last one.

```
cursor.execute(query4, (jobstatus, user_id))
                for rowen in cursor:
                    cont_number = rowen[4]
                     user_screen.cont_number = cont_number
                    print("====>>" + str(cont_number))  

.kv

  Label:
            _id: ""
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.15
            font_size: 35
            text: str(root.cont_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be problem with label and font size. If Label cant display all text it will show what it can, to check it try to use smaller font size or bigger label

```
  Label:
            _id: ""
            font_size: 6
            text: str(root.cont_number)
```

Comment: Unfortunately nope. Changed sizes - same result. But it was good try;)